# Javascript expression to define object's property name?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create this object...

```
object = {
  'object[1][var_name_1]' : 'value1',
  'object[1][var_name_2]' : 'value2',
};
```

I'm trying to it this way, but I'm getting error **missing : after property id**...

```
function getPrefix() {
  return 'object[1]';
}

object = {
  getPrefix() + '[var_name_1]' : 'value1',
  getPrefix() + '[var_name_2]' : 'value2',
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or maybbe it is impossible to set object property name using js experession?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an object literal, each property name can only be identifier rather than an expression, which means you can't use variables. You can only use the square bracket notation on an existing object, so if you have a variable you wish to use as a property name then you'll need to do it after the object is created:

```
var object = {
    '1': {};
};

object[1][var_name_1] = 'value1';
object[1][var_name_2] = 'value2';
```

Comment: I don't want to have "multidimensial" object. I just want property NAME to be 'object[1][var_name_1]'.

Comment: In which case your first code sample will work. I'm not quite clear where the variable bit comes into it now.

Answer (score 5):

You cant set variable properties using literal syntax, but you can set properties using `[]`, after you've created the object:

```
myObject = {}
myObject["any_string_here"] = myValue
```