# Angular: why $index isn't always evaluated inside ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/w2Ltohsq/

Any change (and focus) events on inputs logged via console.log. So, click any input.

I expect console output like:

```
Object {index: 1, 1: Object}
```

but I get:

```
Object {index: 1, $index: Object}
```

So `$index` evaluated and not evaluated in almost the same place.

`ng-repeat="item in List track by index"` and `ng-repeat="(i, item) in List"` didn't help.

**edit**: thanks to everyone, all answers are correct, I am upvoting answer with a working fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a property *named* `$index`. If you want that the property is named with the value of `$index`, you have to use bracket notation:

```
input[$index] = {item: item}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2Ltohsq/1/)

Comment: Duh, I tried it before asking like ``input[$index]['item'] = item`` and it didn't work. Was sure that js will create needed structure on the fly like Perl in this case and hence it is some angular peculiarity too.

Answer (score 2):

```
{ index: $index, $index: { item: item } }
```

is a JavaScript object literal, and the second `$index` is one of the **keys** (fields) of this object. Keys are never evaluated in an object literal. Values are.

Just as in JavaScript, if you write

```
var i = 22;
var obj = {i : i};
```

you'll have a object with one key named `i`, whose value is 22. The code is equivalent to

```
var obj = {'i' : i};
```

I also have a hard time understanding why you have this getTopScope() function.

Comment: I believe the `getTopScope()` method is intended to avoid the need to walk the `$parent` chain--a result of not using an object as the model, with `ng-model` pointing to properties thereof. It's a manifestation of "_If there's not a dot in your model name, you're doing it wrong._" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=32m51s )

Comment: @JAAulde you're probably right. But actually, there is a dot (well, it's a bracket, but it has the same effect) in the model: `input[$index]`. All the OP needs is to add `$scope.input = [];` to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

i believe that this is not a question about angular's $index but instead a question about object literals in javascript.  i do not believe that you can use an expression as the key in the object literal syntax.

[Javascript expression to define object's property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855473/javascript-expression-to-define-objects-property-name)